# How to see updates in Chatter Feed for an object that you don't follow?

Tags: chatter, chatter-feed

I have a group of users working on a number of custom objects. They would like to be aware of the activities of the other group members concerning those custom objects. Chatter (feed) would be a good solution, but alas, Chatter only shows updates for records that you own or follow.

How can I do this? A brute force approach would be to have that group 'auto-follow' any instances of those custom objects. You could do this with an Apex trigger for example.

But is there another, more elegant, solution?